# R BiocCheck: Maybe they are part of a data set loaded with data()?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I got the following message from BiocCheck (for bioconductor):

```
Checking to see if we understand object initialization....
* CONSIDER: Clarifying how objects ‘predict, qnorm, predict, lm,
  coef, nls, coef, head, tail’ (used in .fitCurve, .getLODR,
  .lm2str, .m2str, .plotSigmoid, estimateLOQ , estimateLOQ,
  plotROC, plotScatter) were initialized. Maybe they are part of a
  data set loaded with data(), or perhaps part of an object
  referenced in with() or within().
```

Two of the functions mentioned above:

```
.m2str <- function(m)
{
    eq <- substitute(italic(y) == a + b * italic(x)*','~~italic(r)^2~'='~r2, 
                 list(a  = format(coef(m)[1], digits = 2), 
                      b  = format(coef(m)[2], digits = 2), 
                      r2 = format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 3)))
    as.character(as.expression(eq));
}

.lm2str <- function(data)
{
    return (.m2str(lm(y~x, data)))
}
```

Q: What does the message mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you write these functions as part of a R package? When you call a function like `lm` or `head`, you should specify which R packages these functions originate from (e.g. write `stats::lm` or `utils::head`). This should generally be done for any function not from "base".

Comment: I write those functions in the f package.

Comment: Ok, then just specify the package for each non-base function and it should remove that CONSIDER point.